# Switching to utf-8. White spaces appeared on top of html pages and at some other places

Tags: utf-8

I have switched all html (and php) pages to utf-8. Before that everything looked perfect in any browser for a very long time. Now, when I switched to utf-8 everything (MySQL db and pages), NO other changes were made, the pages look a bit odd. It displays several white rectanges on the page.

Viewing sourse in the browser shows nothing. When I save html page using Save As... (using the default encoding UTF-8 as IE suggests), I see 15 symbols-rectangles on the page. Once I remove them from html page (using Notepad) manually, everything looks almost fine. (Almost = saved html page doesn't display all pictures so I can't tell for sure).

**important additional info:**

1. When I converted all php pages in Notepad++ from ANSI to UTF-8, I chose Encoding->Convert to UTF-8 (not a Convert to UTF-8 without BOM). So, probably, it was converted with BOM.
2. css {padding:0, margin:0} was used a long time to remove white spaces on top a long time ago and was not changed since that time.

Example of several rectanges that I've found on the saved html page (showed here using question symbols):

```
**<BODY>?????? 

<META name=description content="....**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it very much sounds like you have a leading BOM in the page, which usually chokes up browsers. Save the files as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried, it helped a little bit. The upper white bar was reduced to 1 column (I've converted all js, css and php files). The difference before everything looked good is IE: scroll bars appeared in the menu and it looks like IE6.0 (I fixed IE6.0 because of margins problem)... I'm still thinking what I didn't change but looks like I changed everything...   Thank you.

Comment: And here is my comment to the comment above: I forgot to convert 1 folder among many with php files. Now seems like 100% of php files were converted into UTF-8 without BOM. The last top white bar disappeared. IE unexpected bars disappeared. Everything looks perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to encode them using the [entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) for html?